# When creating new User with ASP.Net Identity 2 new row is inserted into parent table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity-2

I am using ASP.Net Identity 2. I created a user as follows:

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
    public virtual Agency Agency { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

The User is a member of an Agency:

```
public class Agency
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string TaxId { get; set; }

    public List<User> Brokers { get; set; } 
}
```

The User has a one to many relationship to Agency. When I am creating a user, I'll retrieve the Agency from the database and then set the `Agency` to the `User`. This is where things go awry.

```
            var manager = Identity.GetUserManager();
            manager.Create(new User()
            {
                UserName = "chuckconway",
                Email = "chuck@winnemen.com",
                FirstName = "Chuck",
                LastName = "Conway",
                Agency = agency

            }, "123");
```

Instead of referencing the Agency and inserting the primary key into the User table, ASP.NET Identity inserts a new agency record into the agency table and uses it's id with the newly created user. I end up with two agencies...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally for one-to-many relationship in EF you want to have an ID (foreign key) of the referencing table included in navigation properties, like this:

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
  public int AgencyId { get; set; } //new
  public virtual Agency Agency { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

then use the `AgencyId` during insert/user creation, as in retrieve `AgencyID` from DB and assign it to `User`